# Differential probe design ground copper pour

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, differential

What is the reason of no copper pour at the differential input side of the board. What would happen if i pour ground copper at that area as well.

[The source of the design](https://xellers.wordpress.com/electronics/1ghz-active-differential-probe/)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The designer probably did that to reduce the capacitance of the probe.

If you filled that area with ground, when you contacted the probe points to your circuit under test, you'd be connecting a capacitance between the probed points, and that could change the behavior of the circuit.

Even without the ground, you're adding some capacitance, but removing the ground minimizes the effect.

Comment: Also, the capacitance would be towards scope ground, which is often but not always the common mode potential of the differential signal. Thus it could skew the signal or add noise.

Answer (score 10):

> *What would happen if i pour ground copper at that area as well.*

The PCB legend implies it's good for 1 GHz. At 1 GHz a 1 pF capacitor has an impedance of 159 ohms. Do you really want to spoil the lack of capacitance at the probing end of the circuit with extra capacitance to ground circa +100 ohms on each input line (because of extending the ground plane)? It may not make that much difference when measuring many circuits but there's no need to do it given the input is differential (by the look of it).

Comment: Hmm you've removed your comment but, strangely and unexpectedly, you've not been on the site since I answered so that's a mystery.

Comment: Hmm even stranger, my original comment and the other comment have now disappeared. Time for some reporting.

Comment: Your comment was removed by a moderator (not me) 8 hours after someone_else* removed his. As the two comments formed a pair and were non technical (relating to how to express 'thanks' on site) and yours made limited sense in isolation (I had considered whether to delete it but left it) then the removal of yours seems reasonable and non mysterious. Someone had possibly flagged it as "no longer needed", as happens. **HOWEVER** the person who deleted nandflash1's comment was not him, doesn't appear to be a moderator and doesn't appear to be a system account so ...?. I'll check further.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon very odd.

Comment: Indeed. I have forwarded a description to 'higher powers'. I suspect it's a bug as there is no obvious commonality between the accounts concerned. TBD.

Comment: Cheers Russ(ell)

Comment: Mystery solved. I quote: "The site engine has a special regexp based subsystem that allows anyone delete comments that contain "thank you" by one no-longer-needed flag without a review." Fancy that .

Comment: Hi, i did not removed my comment. I thanked andy aka for his answer. I will use flag next time.

Comment: OK guys, that seems to clear things up.